# Noise texture rendered as font glyphs

Tags: 22.04

Occasionally, after waking from suspend (`systemctl suspend`) the font glyphs and icons are replaced with color noise texture.

[image: noise glyphs]

The above is the time and date in the top bar. Nearly all text is replaced with the noise texture (the dates in the calendar seem to be unaffected).  What could be the reason? I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.03.